# Facebook API authorization (desktop app)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writting a small desktop application that prvides access to user's facebook account. To check how the things work I use Graph API Explorer. When I'm trying to get a list of my friends everything goes as expected, by when I'm trying to get list of my friend friends, then Graph API Explorer says

```
(#604) Can't lookup all friends of <id_here>. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.
```

There's a question: is there a way to obtain my firend (lets name him Peter) firends list without requiring Peter to use my app (just because Peter doesn't want to use it)?

P.S. I use access token generated in Graph API Explorer if it makes any sense.
P.P.S I use the following `GET` request to obtain friens list:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<Peter's_id>/friends?access_token=<generated_token>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as the message says you can only lookup friends of someone who has authorised your app.

Comment: Err, one more question arises: I create access token in Graph API Explorer using `Get Access Token` button. Now, I want to create a new one (with different permissions), but can't figure out how I can do this. Pressing this button again just opens the window where old token's permissions checkboxes are selected and disabled, so I can turn them off.

Comment: You need to select the additional permissions you want

Comment: WHat if I want to turn off the previous permissions (some of them actually)?

Comment: Make a DELETE request to `/me/permissions?permission=<name of permission to remove>` - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions